# Getting rid of the stains along the tail of a sperm cell

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, shapes, smoothing

[image: figure.1]

I am trying to get the boundary of a sperm cell whose edge should be smooth. However, there are small blob along the tail. I wonder if there is any way that I can remove them, and get a smooth boundary sperm? Attach is the figure, and some code (MATLAB) that I perform.

```
I = imread('asd3.png');
gray = rgb2gray(I);
I = adapthisteq(gray);
[counts,~] = imhist(I,6);
T = otsuthresh(counts);
BW = imbinarize(I,T);
BW2 = bwareaopen(~BW,300);
imshow(BW)
figure
subplot(221),imshow(original)
subplot(222),imshow(gray)
subplot(223),imshow(BW)
subplot(224),imshow(BW2)
```

I will get a figure as:

[image: figure.2]

Can I improve the figure to the following?

[image: figure.3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that the noise have quite a lot of mass. To remove this mass I used the skeleton image:

```
BW = bwmorph(BW,'skel',inf);
```

Which will give you the sperm cell as a tree structure, the backbone is now the longest connected path in this tree. To find this I use the function by Brett Schoelson, which you can find [here](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/216519-skeleton-prunning-for-ocr) (or you can make your own). I find that to make the detection of the longest line a bit more robust, it is good to thicken everything slightly first. Thus we end up with

```
I = imread('sperm.png');
BW1 = ~imbinarize(rgb2gray(I)); %Make the spermcell "true"

%Find backbone
BW2 = bwmorph(BW1,'thicken',5);
[BW3,~] = longestConstrainedPath(BW2,'thinOpt','Skel');
```

Now we just have to rebuild the sperm-cell around this backbone, the head is easily found using morphological open

```
head = imopen(BW1,strel('disk',10,0));
```

and the tail is found by dilating the backbone

```
%Thicken backbone
stats = regionprops(BW1-head,'Area');
area = stats.Area;
len = sum(BW3(:));
stem = imdilate(BW3,strel('disk',floor(0.5*area/(2*len)),0));
```

where the amount to dilate is the thickness of the original tail, which can be approximated by the area of the tail divided by the length. Though due to the artifacts, this is too thick, I reckoned that half the area is the tail and the other half was the artifacts.

As we have the head and the tail, the total cell can be found by adding them and inverting.

```
sperm = ~(stem+head);
```

which gives

[image: Cleaned sperm-cell]

**NOTES:** Assuming you want better accuracy

1) The longest path is not completely the correct path, as it choses the wrong ending, this can possibly be improved by removing spurs.

2) I have used the easiest reconstruction possible by assuming equal width of the tail. This can possibly be improved my doing more measurement of the original picture.

Comment: thank you! it works almost perfect, I think I'll need to add the last step smoothing the stem, do you have any recommendation.  I will also try to deal with some clustered pictures to see if will also work.

Comment: Once you have found the longest path, `BW3` you can ask for the points, sort then and then apply some function smoothing to that set of points.